# Trying to iterate through HashMap and add to JComboBox

Tags: java

I'm trying to iterate through the HashMap and add the contents to the ComboBox. However, it fires off a null error.

```
ComboBoxModel jComboBox1Model = 
                        new DefaultComboBoxModel();


            Iterator it = cashCheckout.products.keySet().iterator();
            while(it.hasNext())
            {
                jComboBox1.addItem(cashCheckout.products.get(it.next()));
            }

            jComboBox1 = new JComboBox();
            getContentPane().add(jComboBox1);


            jComboBox1.setModel(jComboBox1Model);
            jComboBox1.setBounds(362, 139, 111, 22);
```

CashCheckout:

```
public class Checkout {
    //Add Products class to the Checkout
    Products pd = new Products();
    //Add the Hashmaps that were created in Products class.
    HashMap<String, ProductDetails> products = pd.getProductsHashmap();
    HashMap<String, ProductDetails> scanned = pd.getScannedHashmap();
```

The GUI then fires off errors complaining at the addItem line. NullPointerException, even though this HashMap is populated. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `jComboBox1` that's not initialized. You initialize it after you try to populate it.

Change your code to :

```
        jComboBox1 = new JComboBox();
        Iterator it = cashCheckout.products.keySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            jComboBox1.addItem(cashCheckout.products.get(it.next()));
        }
```

Comment: @james111 I've never used a `JComboBox`, but it looks like you are adding `Object`s to it, and `getSelectedItem()` returns the selected `Object`. If you want to print a specific property of that `Object`, cast it to its actual type and call the relevant method to get that property.

Answer (score 0):

Move the line

```
jComboBox1 = new JComboBox();
```

to above where you first use jComboBox1, so:

```
jComboBox1 = new JComboBox();
Iterator it = cashCheckout.products.keySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
    jComboBox1.addItem(cashCheckout.products.get(it.next()));
}
```